# Google Visualization Query not executing callback on upgrading chrome to Version 50.0.2661.87 m

Tags: google-visualization

I am using Google Visualization Query to query my spreadsheet, it was working fine till 49th version. On upgrading chrome to 50th version it stopped working.

The response is very uncertain. Sometimes it returns to callback function and sometimes not. This is my piece of code.

```
var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent("select *");

var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gC_p1taPA9SZWxqpO2blC0hyVLRHCbd2miAXhcqfFYo/gviz/tq?tq=" + encodedQuery + "&gid=0");

query.send(handleQueryResponse);

function handleQueryResponse(){
/**This is my callback function**/
}
```

Please help me what should i do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: works fine for me with `Version 50.0.2661.87 m (64-bit)` -- what gviz version are you loading? any JQuery on the page? any errors in console?

Comment: I am loading version 1.0 of the google visualization.

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"], callback:    function() {var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent("select *");

var query = new google.visualization.Query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gC_p1taPA9SZWxqpO2blC0hyVLRHCbd2miAXhcqfFYo/gviz/tq?tq=" + encodedQuery + "&gid=0");

query.send(handleQueryResponse);    }});

this is my overall query.

Comment: I would recommend using the updated `loader.js` instead of `jsapi` -- see [Load the Libraries](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs)

Comment: @WhiteHat I updated my library to loader.js but still i am facing the same issue. The callback does not fire every time. Is there any limitation with using google visualization query.